# Привязка данных в MVVM для TitleTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Как привязать данные к TitleTemplate?

Делаю так:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <View:WindowTitleView DataContext="{Binding WindowTitle}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
```

Но данные не привязываются, и в WindowTitleView нет данных из VM.

Но если так сделать внутри самого окна, то все работает:

```
<Border DockPanel.Dock="Right">
    <View:WindowTitleView DataContext="{Binding WindowTitle}"/>
</Border>
```

Вот разметка WindowTitleView:

```
<Grid>        
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="210"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
    <local:TitleView Grid.Column="0"/>
    <local:TitlePortView Grid.Column="2"
                    DataContext="{Binding TitlePort}"/>
    <local:ClockView Grid.Column="3"
                     DataContext="{Binding TitleClock}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: Возможно, `MetroWindow` для шаблона `Title` устанавливает `DataContext` самостоятельно, и вы ищете `WindowTitle` не в том `DataContext`'e, в котором ожидаете. Попробуйте задать `DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/></DataTemplate>` и посмотрите, название какого типа выведется.

Comment: @VladD ничего не выводит( и если в vm создать тестовую текстовую переменную, и привязаться к ней, то текст блок ее не видит(

Comment: А где вы задаете `DataContext` окну `Controls:MetroWindow`?. Если в Xaml то возможно привязка идет не в той последовательности

Comment: @Gardes в методе OnStartup в классе App

Comment: Хорошо, давайте ещё проще попробуем: `<DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="TEST"/></DataTemplate>`. Видно `TEST` в окне?

Comment: Да, я это первым делом проверил)

Comment: Окей, тогда может быть там `null`? Это можно проверить вот как: привяжитесь через пустой конвертер (`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EmptyConverter}}"/>`), поставьте breakpoint в функции `Convert`, и посмотрите, что приходит.

Comment: @VladD не совсем понял...

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Добавил код сверху.

Comment: @VladD а сама реализация конвертера?

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: А любая, например `return value;`. Вам же главное, посмотреть, что пришло на вход через breakpoint.

Comment: @VladD а можете показать реализацию?  я таким никогда не пользовался
а когда просто пытаюсь вернуть пустой object вылетает ошибка.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Вот: https://pastebin.com/4qSVLf1g

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Как положить конвертер в ресурсы, знаете?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75185/discussion-between-uporotayapanda-and-vladd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как показал эксперимент, в `TitleTemplate` передаётся не `DataContext` okna, a `Title`. Это не то, что нам нужно, поэтому нам придётся достучаться до `DataContext`'а окна.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <View:WindowTitleView
            DataContext="{Binding DataContext.WindowTitle,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
```

Comment: Все работает! Вы, как всегда, выручаете!

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!